# How to make rounded and bordered button android?

Tags: android, button, android-drawable

I am making a rounded and bordered button. But I am getting button with only primary color in the theme.
Here is my code in circular button drawable file:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/green" />
    <corners android:radius="50dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="10dp"
        android:color="@color/red_primary" />
</shape>
```

here is my button code:-

```
               <Button
                android:id="@+id/feedback_btn"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circular_button"
                android:text="@string/send_feedback"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
also add app:backgroundTint="@null" in Button tag.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use bewlo code for  rounded and bordered button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/BlueDark"/>
    <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="@color/White" />
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
        android:topRightRadius="30dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="30dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"/>

    <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp"
        android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>
```

Also YOU can set boder wedith with bewlo line

```
<stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="@color/White" />
```